# TCPDF / HTML2PDF

Tags: php, tcpdf, html2pdf

I am trying to understand what is the interest of HTML2PDF versus using directly TCPDF.
In order words, What are the benifit of HTML2PDF ? Why it's better that use directly TCPDF ?

Answer (score 8):

as you know HTML2PDF (for PHP 5.x) is based on TCPDF.

HTML2PDF handles HTML better than TCPDF, and HTML2PDF can use CSS Classes, and have a couple more of cool functions, specially for dynamic content which TCPDF alone does not handle well. think of it as "TCPDF++"

Download HTML2PDF or go to [their website](http://www.html2pdf.fr/en/example) and look at the examples, they will show you better than me!!

Don't forget to set [`set_time_limit()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) when generating large documents, to know why look @ [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10017347/issue-with-html2pdf-not-rendering-pdf/10017451).

Answer (score 2):

For some developers, it is *faster* to write a template that produces specific HTML instead of expressly making all of the necessary API calls to build the PDF one piece of text and one box at a time.

I'm personally a big fan of [wkhtmltopdf](https://github.com/antialize/wkhtmltopdf), which uses the popular, powerful and standards-compliant WebKit rendering engine.  Most common HTML-to-PDF programs either don't understand CSS, or understand CSS poorly.