# Issue with HTML2PDF, not rendering PDF

Tags: php, html, pdf, tcpdf, html2pdf

For some reason the HTML2PDF/TCPDF is not rendering the PDF... and I have no idea why... :S

[render.php (main file)](http://pastebin.com/6FEqd9Vf)

[form.php](http://pastebin.com/7y1ed8Y0)

**(The links will lead you to the code im trying to use, so you can test it, you will only need the HTML2PDF Class)**

can somebody tell me why the form isn't rendering??? I'm freaking out!!!

thanx in advance!!

Comment: Any particular error you encountered?

Comment: the funny thing is that there is no error catch from the class and neither from php or apache. thats the thing that's freaking me out. I also should point that this is the first time I used HTML2PDF or any PDF generation class, so I hope somebody has a clue...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer was the execution time.

Solved it by using the `set_time_limit()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Check the webserver logs for any html2pdf-related errors. If you're using apache, command will look like this:

```
tail -f -n 500 /var/log/apache2/error.log
```

Updated my answer since if pdf gets rendered but is empty, it's not a permission issue.

Comment: BluesRockAddict, have you checked the files, There is no problem with the permissions, when I take out the HTML/form it renders the pdf (empty)

Comment: $html2pdf->writeHTML($content, isset($_GET['vuehtml'])); - looks like the correct name is WriteHTML (i.e. with capital W).

Comment: I changed it but it didnt make any change. :S

Comment: no, thats freaking strange... no errors of any kind, just wont render.

Comment: What happens if you do $html2pdf->WriteHTML("<html><body><p>Test</p></body></html>")? Do you get "Test" in pdf or is it still empty?

Comment: HTML2PDF class auto generates the html and body tags, i tried small structures and its all ok, the problem is when I try to load "heavy" forms

Comment: Quick google search indicated that html2pdf doesn't work well with complex html documents, you might want to try using fpdf/mpdf instead.